# If $\sup_{[0,1]} |\rho_n(t) - \rho(t)| \to 0$, does it hold that for holomorphic $f$ and $\rho$ C^1, $\sup_{[0,1]} |f(\rho_n(t)) - f(\rho(t))| \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

$f$ is defined on an open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $\rho : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ is C^1. I tried to prove that $f$ was uniformly continuous, since then it seems to work. But we can't, all we know is that $f$ is holomorphic. I am very stuck and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since ρ is C1, it is Lipschitz continuous. That means there exists K such that |ρ(t) - ρ(s)| < K|t - s| for all t, s in [0, 1].
By definition holomorphy, for each x in Ω is open, Ux and Mx such that |f(y) - f(x)| < Mx|y - x| for all y in Ux. For any n, consider the image ρn([0, 1]). This is a compact subset of Ω, so we can cover finitely many sets Ux. Let U be the union of these finitely sets.
Then, any t, s in [0, 1], |ρn(t) - ρn(s)| < K|t - s|, so ρn([0, 1]) is contained in U. Also, |f(ρn(t)) - f(ρn(s))| < M|ρn(t) - ρn(s)| < MK|t - s|.
Therefore f is uniformly continuous on ρn([0, 1]).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\rho$ has image in $\Omega$, otherwise the question makes no sense. Now, its image is compact, because $\rho$ is continuous. Since $\rho_n\to\rho$ uniformly, there is an open set $\Omega_0$ such that $\overline{\Omega_0}$ is compact and contained in $\Omega$, and such that for large enough $n$, the images of the $\rho_n$ are contained in $\Omega_0$.

Since $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, it follows $f’$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{\Omega_0}$. Therefore…

If you fill this in correctly, you’ll see that $\rho$’s being $C^1$ is not necessary, and $f$ being holomorphic is also not necessary. It is enough that the $\rho$’s are continuous and $f$ is locally Lipschitz (guaranteed if $f$ is $C^1$ on $\Omega$). You can also weaken the assumptions further at the cost of being more careful with the argument.